Qgis2Web Inegi Mexico Shapefile Vectors Not Showing
I am trying to export a vector layer from an INEGI shape file with Qgis2Web. Neither Preview nor Export show any data. I previously used other shape files without any issues.
QGIS 3.38.3-Grenoble
qgis2web 3.22.0



Can you upload the data somewhere and link it here? If you activate the Python console before clicking "Preview" you will have further details on the error

Try with leaflet instead of openlayers. Another thing. I noticed that the coordinate system of Mexico´s Map is lambert conformal conic by INEGI. Try reprojecting the layer to EPSG 4326.

@andreaordonselli here is a link to the shape file. I noticed that the export of the shape file as estados_0.js is 32MB. Not sure if that is too large? estados mexicanos 2010

I also noticed that the export of the shape file as estados_0.js is 32MB. Not sure if that is too large? I opened the Python console but do not get any additional information. @GerardoJimenez I reprojected to EPSG 4326 and used leaflet. No change in the output

@Mecky As you when I try to use Openlayer I get no map. When I use Leaflet with the map in epsg 4326 I get the map.

@GerardoJimenez I tried to just set the projection in ?roject Properties to 4326 and that did not work. Exporting it as explained below by Andrea did work.

Change the projection in the layer settings does not change the coordinate system. Yo have to reproject the layer. You have to do as Andrea described. First expor the layer choosing the CRS as epsg 4326. Then you can play with the reprojected layer in qgis 2web

Check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23SBfzvvHkg. It does explain 3 different ways to do it.

QGIS can correctly project the features drawn with the custom CRS, but qgis2web, which uses proj4js, cannot.
You need to provide a known CRS.
Export your layer like this, I used EPSG 4326 and add it back to the map


Export again with qgis2web, this is the result

